# Accumulated sum vs cumulative sum

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Is there a difference in meaning between *accumulated sum* and *cumulative sum*? In this case we are talking about prizes we collect.

Comment: Accumulated has the sense of being built up over time.  *He's accumulated a large fortune*  Cumulative has the sense of being a running tally.

Comment: "Accumulated sum" suggests to me the total, less any outgoings, of all the prizes you have ever won, that is, if you keep all your winnings in a dedicated bank accout, and possibly spend some the "accumulated sum" would be the balance in that account. "Cumulative sum", on the other hand, sounds like the total amount you won at one event, during one season, or over the course of one year of the activity for which you have won prizes. Depending on how much you spend the accumulated sum could be higher or lower than any particular cumulative sum.

Answer (score -1):

"accumulated" means that somehow track is being kept of the cumulative sum.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  I don't understand how an "accumulated sum" would differ from a "cumulative sum" based on this statement.

Comment: @Hellion, Suppose I have a long list of numbers that I have added up.  I could have proceeded by adding the first two to find a subtotal, then adding in the third to get a new subtotal, and so on.  The subtotal in this process is, at each stage, a cumulative sum.  The ending total, after I have added up all the figures, is the accumulated sum.  Each of the preceding subtotals, however, are only cumulative sums, not the accumulated sum.  Come to think of it, "subtotal" is approximately what "cumulative sum" means, where "total" means "accumulated sum".

Comment: Thank you all for your answers :) Greg Lee, your explanation gives me a new  perspective of the subject. I really appreciate your comment.

Comment: @GregLee please edit your explanation into your answer. As it stands, your answer is turning up in the low quality queue..